# I want to send image and text separately when share button click first send image than text

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am Working on Android App which I want to share data button now it is sending in one message I want to send it in different when on the share button click two messages send one is image second is text
Here is my code it is working fine both send in one message

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("image/*");
        

        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Click on this Link get the Location of a customer https://maps/+latitude+","+Longtitude);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Screenshot"));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want two "shares" then make two `startActivity` calls for different `Intent`s, but note that first will start third party app (after picking from chooser) and your lose focus, so probably second call will be made after back to your app.

when you send `Intent` like above then third-party app gets whole passed content and is placing it in message/mail/memory/whatever. there is no method/flag/bundle param forcing splitting passed data to separated messages. in it would exist then in your current code you have three extras, so three messages would be sent (one with empty title only...)

in short: one `Intent` = one action occurs, and is resolved by third-party, you can't control it